# Database multithreading with preserved sequence updates on primary key

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, parallel-processing, amazon-dynamodb

Having a lot of data to process I was trying to make them parallel.

```
class Item{
    Integer id;
    String data;
}


ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for (Item item : items) {
            executor.execute(() -> putItemToDB(item));
        }
```

But the problem that occurs was that in a test case i have first 6 tasks to the same primary key. The order of tasks with the same primary key(id) is important and must not be changed. Currently, I don't have guarantee of that.

Example:

```
items = [{id: 1, data: "a"}, {id: 1, data: "b"}, {id: 2, data: "g"}]
```

I have to know that `a` was **before** `b`, and running all tasks in threadpool don't guarantee that. There is possibility, that `a` will override `b`.

Is there any good design pattern to solve that problem?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking, since there's nothing in this code that reveals what *"the order of tasks with the same primary key"* actually means.

Comment: I have improoved my question. I hope it is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Good design pattern for this use case is to use separate Actor instance for each id. Items are send to the corresponding actor and are kept in order in the input queue. Actor takes next items from the queue and saves in the database.
To find an actor for the key, a HashMap can be used.

If there are too many different ids and so too many actors, actor can check that if its input queue is empty for some time, then deregister itself from the HashMap.

Also such an actor can be optimized so that instead of input queue, a variable for single item can be used. If another item arrives when previous item is not yet written in the database, new item simply rewrites over previous item - anyway, writing the old item has no sense, it is going to be overwritten in the database.

A simple actor to start with can be found at https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/actor/simpleactor/SimpleActor.java

Comment: I have simplified my question, because i didn't want to make it too complicated, but i have to had every record saved id DB, even if it'll be overwritted. Thank for your answer, i'll read about it more.